# Defaul check all en primeng p-multiselect

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

¿ Como puedo seleccionar todo el contenido de un **p-multiselect** de **primeng** de manera predeterminada al cargar la pagina ?

Desde este **p-multiselect** envío datos y los recibo, pero solo necesito hacer la selección automática cuando consulto la data.

De momento tengo este código:

**Template:**

```
<div class="p-field">
      <label style="color: black; text-align: center !important;">Almacén</label>
      <p-multiSelect formControlName="controlStore" placeholder="Seleccione Un Almacen" [options]="dataStores" [filter]="true" [(ngModel)]="selectedStores" optionLabel="store" optionValue="storeId" ></p-multiSelect>
</div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
  SelectedBusiness(business: string){
    this.filteredBusimess = 'TODOS' ? this.filteredFormat : this.filteredFormat.filter(element => element.businessType == business)
    let hashStores = {};
    this.dataStores = this.filteredBusimess.filter(o => hashStores[o.storeId] ? false : hashStores[o.storeId] = true)
  }
```